# Как в IE заставить работать правило input:-ms-input-placeholder:after?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Возможно ли в IE применить правило для

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder:after{}
```

?

В остальных браузерах работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, официально никакими стандартами не поддерживается. Псевдоэлементов для псевдоэлементов не существует. Если это где-то работает, то это деталь реализации, на которую нельзя полагаться.

Ищите иное решение, которое не использует подобных конструкций.